# cannot open ADODB connection

Tags: .net, vb.net, adodb

I'm trying to open a connection with the following function:

```
Public cn1 As New ADODB.Connection
    'Sub to open connection to database 
    Public Function OpenConnection(ByVal strOpenConnectionString As String, _
                                   Optional ByVal lngOpenConnectionTimeout As Long = 3600) As Long
        With cn1
            .CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
            .Mode = ADODB.ConnectModeEnum.adModeUnknown
            .ConnectionTimeout = lngOpenConnectionTimeout
            .CommandTimeout = lngOpenConnectionTimeout
            .ConnectionString = strOpenConnectionString
        End With
        Try
            cn1.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString())
        End Try

        OpenConnection = cn1.State
    End Function
```

I'm using windows authentication for my connection and my connection string is:

```
"Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Test;Data Source=PEDRAM-PC\PEDRAM"
```

I can connect easily when I use an sql connection but I need to do it with that ado db object because it's my company code.
I get the following exception:
[image]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: i assume you have ommited user id and password intentionally?
http://www.connectionstrings.com/ is a good site, which may be useful.

Comment: no username and passwords are required i guess because i'm using windows authentication and not sql authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a different connection string for ADODB. Try This

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Initial Catalog=Test;Data Source=PEDRAM-PC\PEDRAM;Trusted_connection=yes;
```